# Cannot Solve "unexpected end-of-file found" Error

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I am creating a class for blocks in my simple OpenGL game using Visual C++ 2012 and have ran into a weird error.  This is the complete error:

- *Message*- error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
- *File*- block.cpp
- *Line*- 27
- *Column*- 1

Here is the code:

**block.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "agent.h"
#include <Engine2D/spritebatch.h>

class Block {
public:
    Block(glm::vec2 dim, glm::vec4 uv, glm::vec2 pos, GLuint texture);
    // Draws the block to the sprite batch
    void draw(e2d::SpriteBatch& spriteBatch);
    // Returns the position
    glm::vec2 getPosition();
    // Returns the size
    glm::vec2 getSize();
private:
    glm::vec2 _dim;
    glm::vec4 _uv;
    glm::vec2 _pos;
    GLuint _texture;
};
```

**block.cpp**

```
#include "block.h"

Block::Block(glm::vec2 dim, glm::vec4 uv, glm::vec2 pos, GLuint texture) :
    _dim(dim),
    _uv(uv),
    _pos(pos),
    _texture(texture)
{}

void Block::draw(e2d::SpriteBatch& spriteBatch) {

    spriteBatch.draw(glm::vec4(_pos.x, _pos.y, _dim.x, _dim.y), _uv, e2d::color(), 0.0f, _texture);

}

glm::vec2 Block::getPosition() {

    return _pos;

}

glm::vec2 Block::getSize() {

    return _dim;

}
 // ERROR LINE
```

If you find the problem or can elaborate on the cause it would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

**Note:**

- The Engine2D/spritebatch.h is part of the engine that I have created.  It simply draws and renders objects to the screen.  This class is and could not be related to the issue.
- The glm namespace is for the OpenGL Mathematics library.  It contains useful vector and matrix classes along with functions for calculating things like distance between two points.
- When I use e2d::color, it is creating a struct with RGBA color values inside.  It is part of my engine and the default constructor for this sets all the RGBA values to 255.

Comment: check in your header file, if you have missing semicolons or #endif guards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I have looked back through it, I have discovered the cause of the error.  It is because I included my agent.h class and never did anything with it.  Oops!

Comment: i dont think that should matter if the agent.h is empty or not

Comment: @Gabriel I don't know.  I just noticed it, deleted it, and it worked.